# Is it possible to run methodnameX depending on X value?

Tags: java, methods

If there are 3 methods in

```
public class Hero extends GameCharacter {

public void test1(){}; 
public void test2(){}; 
public void test3(){};
```

is it possible while running this in

```
public class MainClass extends ApplicationAdapter implements InputProcessor {
@Override
public void create () {
private Hero mainHero;
For (int x = 0; x < 0; x++)
    ....
```

to run

```
mainhero.testx
```

?

Comment: You could use Java reflection for this, or implement an annotation pricessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could using reflection, but you should evaluate better patterns for this.

Alternative solutions include

Conditionals

```
public void test(int x){
    switch (x) {
       case 1:
          // Things for x == 1
          break;
    }
};
```

OOP, for when you have different types of Heroes

```
public abstract class Hero extends GameCharacter {
    public abstract void test();
}

public class Hero1 extends Hero {
    @Override
    public void test() {}
}

...

List<Hero> heroes  = ... ;
heroes.add(new Hero1());
for (Hero h : heroes) { h.test(); }
```

Or, just call all your test methods separately via independent unit-testing methods.

Answer (score 3):

This situation is suitable for [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Basically you have a variation in functionality, so you create an interface for executing it, and create multiple implementations of it. It could look something like this:

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public static interface TestStrategy {
        void test();
    }

    public static class Test1 implements TestStrategy {

        @Override
        public void test() {
            System.out.println("1");
        }

    }

    public static class Hero {
        TestStrategy test[] = new TestStrategy[]{
            //either use defined class
            new Test1(),
            //or inline
            () -> {System.out.println("2");}
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hero hero = new Hero();
        for (int i = 0; i < hero.test.length; i++) {
            hero.test[i].test();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested before, you could use reflection for this. This example uses reflection to demonstrate that.

```
public void callYourClassMethod(String x) {
  try {
    YourClass yourClass = new YourClass()
    Method method = YourClass.class.getDeclaredMethods("methodname" + x);
    method.setAccessible(true); // Only needed if it's not accessible from calling class.
    method.invoke(yourClass); // Assuming your method doesn't take any arguments.
  } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
    System.err.println("Method methodname" + x + "is not declared.");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```